# Grothendieck type vanishing result for Local Cohomology over not necessarily affine schemes?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, sheaf-cohomology, projective-schemes, local-cohomology

Let $(X,\mathcal O_X)$ be a Noetherian, affine Scheme and $\mathcal F$ be a quasi-coherent Sheaf of $\mathcal O_X$-modules on $X$. Let $\dim \mathcal F$ be the Krull dimension of $\{x\in X| \mathcal F_x\ne0\}$. Let $Z$ be a closed subset of $X$, then it is known that  the local cohomology $H^i_Z(X,\mathcal F)=0,\forall i>\dim \mathcal F$ .

My question is: Is any such result, for vanishing of Local Cohomology, known for general, not necessarily affine, Noetherian schemes (even for coherent sheaves) or at least say for projective schemes ?

Comment: Have you tried to apply the long exact sequence $\cdots \to H^i_Z(X, \mathcal{F}) \to H^i(X, \mathcal{F}) \to H^i(U, \mathcal{F}) \to \cdots$ where $U$ is the complement of $Z$ in $X$? Then because $\operatorname{Dim} U \le \operatorname{Dim} X$ we get the vanishing you want by nothing that the cohomological dimension of $U$ (resp. $X$) is bounded by the dimension of $U$ (resp. the dimensoon of $X$).

Comment: @user45878: yeah well, in general, the long exact sequence would only give us that for $j>1$, we have $H^j_Z(X,\mathcal F)=0, \forall j >1+\dim X$ ... and in general, $\dim Supp \mathcal F$ is usually smaller than $\dim X$, so that's why I would like some bound in terms of $\dim Supp \mathcal F$ ...

Comment: @user45878: I guess you could slightly do better than what I said in my previous comment, actually $H^j_Z(X,\mathcal F)=0,\forall j>\max \{ \dim X, 1+\dim (X\setminus Z) \}$ ... but I really can't see how you could get a bound in terms of $\dim Supp \mathcal F$ by only looking at the long exact sequence (and indeed I'm not even sure even if such a bound exists or not ...)

Comment: First of all I think we expect $j \ge 1 + \operatorname{Dim} X$, but maybe I am getting confused. Moreover, it should be possible to reduce to the case that the support of $\mathcal{F}$ is equal to $X$. Indeed, it is probably true that $H^i_Z(X, \mathcal{F}) \cong H^i_{Z \cap \operatorname{Supp} \mathcal{F}}(\operatorname{Supp} \mathcal[F}, \mathcal{F}))$. A proof of that fact probably follows by considering the long exact sequence for the pair $(X,U)$ and for the pair $(\operatorname{Supp} \mathcal{F}, \operatorname{Supp} \mathcal{F} \cap U)$ (there should be a map oong exact sequences).